# Flow type extends generic type and private member with symbol

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to add flow type to my code and I have some issue with
Generic types, I want to write something like this `T extends Object`
to be able to use `obj.constructor.name` and so on.
Also, I have issue with Symbol in class
please see following code

```
const postProcessors = new Symbol("postProcessors");

class Container<T extends Object> {
    [postProcessors]: PostProcessor[];

    constructor() {
        this[postProcessors] = [];
    }

    enablePostProcessor(postProcessor: PostProcessor) {
        this[postProcessors].push(postProcessor);
    }

    getInstance<T>(constructor: T): T{
        //...
    }
}
```